# Radio button não salva no banco

Tags: php

Não estou conseguindo fazer o *radio button* escolhido ir para o banco

```
<form method="post" action="functions/modalQuiz.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                     aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Quiz Brutus</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h3><?= $col2['pergunta']; ?></h3>
                                <input type="hidden" name="pergunta" value="<?= $col2['pergunta']; ?>">
                                <hr>
                                <label for="radio"><input type="radio" id="radio" name="resposta" value="<?= $col2['resposta1']; ?>"> <?= $col2['resposta1']; ?></label>
                                <hr>
                                <label for="radio2"><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="resposta" value="<?= $col2['resposta2']; ?>">  <?= $col2['resposta2']; ?></label>
                                <hr>
                                <label for="radio3"><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="resposta" value="<?= $col2['resposta3']; ?>">  <?= $col2['resposta3']; ?></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Salvar</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

E esse é o *PHP* que vai recebê-lo.

```
include("conexao.php");

$pergunta = $_POST['pergunta'];
$resposta = $_POST['resposta'];

$insert = "INSERT INTO modalquiz(pergunta, resposta) VALUES ('$pergunta','$resposta')";
mysqli_query($conn, $insert);
//header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Comment: Verificou os logs de erros do seu servidor? Poderia colocar as últimas linhas dele na pergunta?

Comment: Ola Anderson, eu achei o problema, um modal dismiss estava cancelando a operação.

Comment: Problema agora é que eu preciso retornar todos os modais, finalizando o primeiro precisa aparecer o segundo, mas ele volta com o header do .php na qual enviei o form